# onclick open window pass variable using document.getElementByID

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, window

What am I doing wrong?

```
<input type='text' name='keyword' id='keyword' size='16'>

<a href= "" onclick="window.open('http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=document.getElementById('keyword')');">
```

it opens a new window with without q = keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `getElementById` enclosed in quotes.

It should be:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open('http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + document.getElementById('keyword').value);">
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `document.getElementById('keyword')` as part of the code, not the hyperlink.

```
<input type='text' name='keyword' id='keyword' size='16'>  

<a href= "" 
    onclick="window.open('http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + document.getElementById('keyword') + '');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `document.getElementById('keyword')`doesn't automatically give you the value written in it. For that, you need to do `document.getElementById('keyword').value`.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=' + document.getElementById('keyword').value);">Click here</a>
```